# How to make methods for a boolean attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I set a boolean to false in a method?

For my BusinessStore search I am trying to make 3 different radio buttons to choose from for **Online Stores**, **Offline Stores** and **All Stores**.

This my `BusinessStore` model and the 3 methods I am trying to make for the radio buttons:

```
attr_accessible :online_store # boolean attribute

def online_search
   business_store.online_store = true
end

def offline_search
   business_store.online_store = false
end

def all_search
   # Give all results whether true or false
end
```

How do I finish this and what needs to be corrected?

---

**UPDATE**

```
Product.rb

def search_type=(boolean)
   case (boolean)
    when 'online'
      @online_search = true
      @offline_search = false
    when 'offline'
      @online_search = false
      @offline_search = true
    when 'all'
      @online_search = true
      @offline_search = true
    else
    @online_search = true
    @offline_search = true
   end
end

search/index.html.erb

<%= label_tag :search_type, "All" %>
   <%= radio_button_tag :search_type, "all" %>
<%= label_tag :search_type, "Online" %>
    <%= radio_button_tag :search_type, "online" %>
<%= label_tag :search_type, "Offline" %>
    <%= radio_button_tag :search_type, "offline" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a different approach instead and just made two checkboxes:

**SearchController.rb**

```
def index
  @search = Product.search do
   q.with(:online_search, params[:online_search] == 1) if params[:online_search].nil?
   q.with(:offline_search, params[:offline_search] == 0) if params[:offline_search].nil?
  end
  @products = @search.results
end
```

**search/index.html.erb**

```
  <%= label_tag :online_search, 'Online' %>
    <%= check_box_tag :online_search, params[:online_search], true %>
  <%= label_tag :offline_search, 'Offline' %>
    <%= check_box_tag :offline_search, params[:offline_search], true %>
```

I set the checkboxes to start out as already checked for both in order to search online and offline unless one of them is unchecked. This is why in the search controller I search for the params being nil or not for both methods.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably have an easier time making a wrapper method that interprets the selection instead of having direct-mapped mutators:

```
def search_method=(value)
  case (value)
  when 'online'
    @online_search = true
    @offline_search = false
  when 'offline'
    @online_search = false
    @offline_search = true
  else
    @online_search = true
    @offline_search = true
  end
end

def online_search?
  @online_search
end

def offline_search?
  @offline_search
end
```

Then you make a selection between `online`, `offline` and `all` or whatever default you'd prefer.

**Edit:** Amended based on gist:

```
def index
  @search = Product.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
    paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
    order_by(:purchase_date, :desc)
    order_by(:price,:asc)

    includes(:business_store)
    where(:business_store => { :online_store => true })
  end
  @products = @search.results
end
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new at ruby on rails, what's a wrapper method? Also, using `business_store.online_store = false` to pass as online store = false right?

Comment: A wrapper method is a generic programming term for a method that encapsulates a simple operation by applying a bit of abstraction. I think you have to set both online and offline, though, not just one of them.

Comment: This is confusing for me because I can't really picture how the controller or view would be set up with that method. Is there an alternative way?

Comment: Is it that you have three different controller actions, one of which will be exercised depending on the option passed in, or that there's one action that searches in different ways?

Comment: Here's is my application code to get the search working, take a look at the SearchController: https://gist.github.com/1392014 . By the way I am using Sunspot (https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) but I don't think their is a big different of how filtering works.

Comment: Do you maybe mean you want to search with filtering? It sounded like you wanted to assign an attribute to something. I've amended my answer with a guess as to how you might do this in Sunspot, but you'd have to read the documentation to be sure.

Comment: You're exactly right, I am trying to filter my search with the above options. I will take a look and then get back to you.